# ng-recaptcha increase the witdh to fill the form elements

Tags: css, angular, recaptcha

I am using ng-recaptcha in my angular 14 application (inside a Reactive form) to implement Google Captcha V2.
All works well except I need to increase the width of the captach to match the other input elements of the form. Here my code:

```
<div class="form-field recaptcha-wrap">
  <re-captcha formControlName="recaptchaSelect" (resolved)="resolved($event)"
   (errored)="onError($event)">
  </re-captcha>
</div>

.recaptcha-wrap {
  transform: scale(1.25);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

The transform property scales the captcha but I want it to stretch it. Here's how it looks now.

[image]